# Espresso Tests stuck when run on multiple devices

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, gradlew

I have a suite of tests written using Espresso that work fine and return result on being run on one device.

When run on multiple devices simultaneously the tests get stuck. I can see that the tests are done and it is not running any more tests but it returns no output.

Any ideas on why this could be happening and how to debug it ?

I have the --debug and --stacktrace flags enabled. Using :

./gradlew connectedAndroidTest --stacktrace --info

Comment: stuck you mean ran on one device and you cannot see running on another device simultaneously or it is stuck on the second once it finishes on the first device? please give more details

Comment: stuck as in it is not returning the result even though I saw it finish on both devices and no more tests are being run.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the results? it will not be on command prompt itself. It will be in build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/(Flavors/XML) Does your connectedAndroidTest says build successful?

Comment: The command does not the return, it stays stuck at some random number % completed and nothing is written to the build/outputs folder either.

Comment: Which OS Windows, Mac or Linux? did you try to kill by command + c?

Comment: Mac, yes I killed it by command + c. I want it to run for CI and cannot be fiddling with it manually, also since I used command + c the reports were not generated.

Comment: do you see your device before running the test like adb devices?

Comment: yup and also I can see the tests getting executed on the devices to begin with.

Comment: thats good. Are you able to see results when you run tests from Android Studio itself? also try ./gradlew clean connectedAndroidTest    sometimes gradle not able to overwrite the existing directories or delete, also try with sudo ./gradlew clean connectedAndroidTest